# if else clause for Dockerfile variable not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following doesn't work in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN if $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -eq ""; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting"; exit 1; else echo "SSH key is set"; fi
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 4/15 : RUN if $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -eq ""; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting"; exit 1; else echo "SSH key is set"; fi
 ---> Running in 3bd29320f0e3
/bin/sh: -eq: command not found
```

I would like to check if the `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable contains anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around your variable (if it might have spaces in it) and simply use `=` operator for string comparison.

In Bourne shell it would be :

```
if [ "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" = "" ]; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting"; exit 1; else echo "SSH key is set"; fi
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but I used `==`. When I replaced it with `=` everything worked. Why? On my local machine both options work fine.

Comment: `=` is POSIX-compliant, and is the only one that is certain to work in both bash and sh, (`==` is bash specific). However they should both work the same for string comparison as far as you have specified `/bin/bash` in your script. Best practice is that if you use single brackets `[ ... ]` then use `=`, if you want to use `==` then use double brackets `[[ ... ]]`. Anyway the problem in the OP's question is that he was using `-eq` which is an arithmetic comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put square brackets there.. Otherwise to test an empty variable is better `-z` switch.

```
RUN if [ -z "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ]; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting"; exit 1; else echo "SSH key is set"; fi
```